# Lost All Contact On My Nexus 4 Device

Tags: nexus-4

I decided to make a new gmail and replace it with my old gmail on my phone so i removed account and then what i put my new gmail id all my contacts are lost and in my call log i only see numbers no names. Can anyone please suggest how i can reverse this?

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts might have been synced with the old Google account. You can try doing this:

1. Login on your computer with the old Gmail. Go to "Contacts" and see if you have all your contacts visible over there. ("Contacts" option will be available on top left, where there is a caption of "Gmail" along with an arrow).
2. If you find your old contacts in the above step, login to your phone with old Gmail Id. You will probably see all your contacts again.
3. Export all the contacts to your phone memory.
4. Login with new Gmail Id.